# How to edit the interval of autosave feature on gedit?

Tags: gedit, text-editor

Can anyone tell me how to change the autosave feature so that it saves in intervals of less than 1 minute?

Comment: Use some other editor. `vim`, for example, can use a plugin to autosave whenever the file changes: https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-auto-save

Comment: but Vim is not gui   :-(

Answer (score 1):

To enable autosave -

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-save true
```

To change autosave interval

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-save-interval n
```

where n is the duration in minutes.

Comment: yes but i want it in second ( less then 1 minute)

Comment: Does it accept fractional values (eg 0.2)? I haven't tried it ...

Comment: invalid value :-(

Comment: Gedit's autosave interval seemingly can only be adjusted at a one-minute resolution.

Comment: You can use Sublime Text with [auto-save](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/auto-save) plugin that automatically saves the current file after every modification.

Comment: Sublime is not free :-(

Comment: Sublime Text may be [downloaded](http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime-text_build-3065_amd64.deb) and evaluated for free and there is no enforced time limit for the evaluation.

Comment: @aliarousyoucef Sublime Text is free in practice.

Comment: I'm in development  not practice or evaluation  @muru & Rohith Madhavan

Comment: @aliarousyoucef Eh? What difference does that make? ["in practice"](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=define+in+practice) doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: please   @muru  can you give me a link confirm that  Sublime Text is free in practice  :-)

Comment: See http://www.sublimetext.com/2: "There is currently no enforced time limit for the evaluation." Therefore, free in practice.

Comment: there is difference between  evaluation and " daily  use and commercial application development "

Comment: Sublime Text 2 may be downloaded and evaluated for free, **however a license must be purchased for continued use**

Comment: [Looking at dconf-editor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n9QgM.png) it can only be set in minutes. Note, there are lots more native linux editors available, some of which probably have auto-save.

Comment: Does gedit autosave flies that have not been assigned a name (have not been saved yet on a disk by the user)?